# Python 2.7.18 has no pip?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and with it came Python 2.7.18rc1. But I found out the worst way possible that pip is nowhere to be found (yet Python 3's pip exists). How come? That's what I find when I execute `sudo find / -name "pip" -print`:

```
/root/.cache/pip
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip
```

and that's it. "pip3" is there, while `/root/.cache/pip` is a folder full of nothing. But whatever happened to pip2? I tried to install pip(2) with both apt-get and Synaptic, but neither worked.

Comment: sometimes you have to install easy_install and/or pip. looking. several search results but I'll let you pick from them (although it's recommended to change to python3, worth the effort, but I know not always that simple)

Comment: did you try? https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-20.04/

Comment: It's probably a subtle hint to stop using Python 2. `pip` has always been separate from the standard library, so it's perfectly reasonable to *not* include `pip` in whatever package provides Python itself.

Comment: @chepner Good point. But why release a crippled version, then? I read that 2.7.18 is a "commemorative" version (hinting that it wasn't in their plans to release it). Like those coins minted to celebrate some special event or date.

Comment: @L.Grozinger That worked, thanks!!! And all I needed was to get scipy installed... :)

Comment: Not including `pip` in the package hardly "cripples" Python.